# Error in shadowing a let variable with a var variable inside a block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lexical-analysis, shadowing, executioncontext

I have heard about shadowing in JS. My question is why can't we shadow a let variable present in global scope with a var variable present inside a block .
Eg->

```
let a =100;
{
 var a =100;
 console.log(a);
}
```

- **Output**:-Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared.

This question came to my mind because I studied that let and var variables are present in different memory locations. So according to me this shouldn't be a problem.

And if there is a problem then why the below code is working

```
var a = 100;
{
let a=10;
console.log(a);
}
```

**Output**:- 10

**Please  provide a detailed answer explaining about the exceution context and variable environment in each case** .

Comment: `var` declarations are interpreted as if they appeared at the top of the closest enclosing `function` or global/module scope. You've got the functionality of `let` and `var` backwards.

Comment: Also "present in different memory locations" is not a correct characterization of the difference between `let` and `var`.

Comment: @pointy that for giving a vague explanation of how let and var works :)

Comment: @pointy I want to know what happens under the hood . Why is there a Block memory space and a Global memory space in chrome debugger . And why exactly it is causing an  issue . :)

Comment: Read the linked duplicate question. There's a huge amount of information there.